# Python: How to compare string from two text files and retrieve an additional line of one in case of match

Tags: python, for-loop, compare, readfile

I have found so much information from previous search on this website but I seem to be stuck on the following issue.

I have two text files that looks like this

Inter.txt ( n-lines but only showed 4 lines,you get the idea)

```
7275
30000
6693
855
....
```

rules.txt (2n-lines)

```
7275
8500
6693
7555
....
3 
1000
8
5
....
```

I want to compare the first line of Inter.txt with rules.txt and in case of a match, I jump for n-lines in order to get the score of that line. (E.g. with 7275, there is a match, I jump n to get the score 3)

I produced the following code but for some reasons, I only have the ouput of the first line when I should have one for each match from my first file. With the previous example, I should have 8 as an output for 6693.

```
import linecache

inter = open("Inter.txt", "r")
rules = open("rules.txt", "r")

iScore = 0
jump = 266
i=0
for lineInt in inter:
    #i = i+1
    #print(i)
    for lineRul in rules:
         i = i+1
         #print(i)
         if lineInt == lineRul:
             print("Match")
             inc = linecache.getline("rules.txt", i + jump)
             #print(inc)
             iScore = iScore + int(inc)         
             print(iScore)
             #break
         else:
             continue
```

All the print(i) are there because I checked that all the lines were read. I am a novice in Python.

To sum up, I don't understand why I only have one output. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think the main thing that blocks you from getting forward is that the for loops on files gets the pointer to the end of the file, and doesn't resets when you starts the loops again.

So when you only open rules.txt once, and uses its intance in the inner loop it only goes through all the lines at the first iteration of the outer loop, the second time it tries to go over the remains lines, which are non.

The solution is to close and open the file outside the inner loop.
This code worked for me.

```
import linecache

inter = open("Inter.txt", "r")

iScore = 0
jump = 4
for lineInt in inter:
    i=0
    #i = i+1
    #print(i)
    rules = open("rules.txt", "r")
    for lineRul in rules:
        i = i+1
        #print(i)
        if lineInt == lineRul:
            print("Match")
            inc = linecache.getline("rules.txt", i + jump)
            #print(inc)
            iScore = iScore + int(inc)         
            print(iScore)
            #break
        else:
            continue

    rules.close()
```

I also moved where you set the i to 0 to the beginning of the outer loop, but I guess you'd find it yourself.

And I changed jump to 4 to fit the example files your gave :p

Comment: Well that did it for me ! I knew something was up with reading up the files but couldn't quite catch what. Thanks for your short answer !

Comment: Have fun experiencing python ^.^

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this solution:

```
def get_rules_values(rules_file):
    with open(rules_file, "r") as rules:
        return map(int, rules.readlines())

def get_rules_dict(rules_values):
    return dict(zip(rules_values[:len(rules_values)/2], rules_values[len(rules_values)/2:]))

def get_inter_values(inter_file):
    with open(inter_file, "r") as inter:
        return map(int, inter.readlines())

rules_dict = get_rules_dict(get_rules_values("rules.txt"))
inter_values = get_inter_values("inter.txt")

for inter_value in inter_values:
    print inter_value, rules_dict[inter_value]
```

Hope it's working for you!

Comment: It worked too ! I chose NK_loco answers as it was closer to my original code and to what I wanted but thanks a lot ! Your answer was also top notch !

Comment: @Hiso Glad you found it helpful!